# Need Help to Understand Simple Vector Subspace Proof of Teacher

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-explanation

**Given**

$X \in M_{nn}(\mathbb{F})$ is a static matrix

$U = \{A \in M_{nn}(\mathbb{F})\ | AX = XA\}$

Proof that $U$ is a subspace of $M_{nn}(\mathbb{F})$.

**Teachers proof**

... uses three steps to proof that.

a) Show that zero element of $M_{nn}(\mathbb{F})$ is in $U$:

(irrelevant)

b) Show that $\forall u1, u2 \in U: u1+u2 \in U $

(irrelevant)

c) Show that for $a \in \mathbb{F}, A \in U: aA \in U$

Let $A \in U$ and $a \in \mathbb{F}$. Then $(aA)X = a(AX) = a(XA) = X(aA)$. So, $aA \in U$.

What?

Looking at this particular step: $a(AX) = a(XA)$

How can she just state that AX = XA? That is not generally true except for n=1. To me (and maybe I'm wrong -that is why I'm asking here for help), nothing is proven. Maybe the fact that the $A$ that is scaled by $a$ is already in U makes that implicit, but shouldn't that be incorporated into the proof? Sorry in case this is a dumb question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Show that for $a \in \mathbb{F}, A \in U: aA \in U$

The string of symbols above does not quite read as a valid mathematical satatement.

What you professor was saying, be it as it may in the amount of predicate logic you'll want to use, is that for all $a\in\Bbb F$ and for all $B\in U$, it holds that $aB\in U$.

With this premise, $B\in U$ and therefore $B$ satisfies the definitory property of $U$, which is that $BX=XB$.

Comment: Sorry about the notation, it was freestyle :D

Comment: @alberteinstein That sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher stated that $A\in U$, so by definition $AX=XA$. That also $aA\in U$ is what you want to show!